# Prove $ 4\times 2^n $ divides $ a^{2^n}-1 $ for all odd a, and $ n \in \Bbb N $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

So I'm pretty sure this is an induction problem. I've got as far as expressing $ a=2k+1 $ , proving this for the base case $ n=1 $ , but I've then got stuck on the inductive step.

I've assumed $$ 2^{m+2} | (k-1)^{2^m} -1 $$

And then I've tried to perform induction on n: $$ (k-1)^{2^{m+1}} = (k-1)^{2^m} \times (k-1)^{2^m} -1 $$

But I'm not sure where to go from here, and whether I've actually done everything right so far. How would one prove the original statement?

Also apologies for bad formatting, I'm somewhat new to latex. Also apologies for bad formality in my attempted proof, I'm learning how to write proofs more formally, but I'm not there yet.

Comment: Where does that $\;k-1\;$ come from? Are you induction on odd integers $\;a\;$ , or on $\;n\;$ ? I think the latter, but reading what you wrote I have doubts...

Comment: Use the fact that $(a^{2^{m+1}}-1)=(a^{2^m}-1)(a^{2^m}+1)$

Comment: @Leo163 is correct. Factorise the expression.

Comment: @Ben I think you meant $\;n\in\Bbb N\;$ , as for example with $\;n=0\;$ we'd get $\;4\cdot2^0=4\,\mid\,(a^1-1)=a-1\;$ *for all odd integers* $\;a\;$, which is false already for $\;a=3\;$ , say.

Comment: @DonAntonio I have edited the question because I don't think it has any meaning for $n≤0$ as it is clearly wrong for some values while most values are fractions for which we cannot use divisibility.

Comment: @tatan I think the same as you, yet I always prefer the OP himself *changes* something in his own post.

Comment: @DonAntonio The OP probably knows this but is too casual to clearly mention that(Just notice the apologisies in the question!). Nevertheless, I did my job.

Answer (score 1):

Induction **on** $\;n\;$ : assuming $\;2^{n+2}\,\mid\,(a^{2^n}-1)\;$, we now prove that $\;2^{n+3}\,\mid\,(a^{2^{n+1}}-1)\;$. But (Leo's comment is right on the money)

$$a^{2^{n+1}}-1=\left(a^{2^n}-1\right)\left(a^{2^n}+1\right)$$

Now, $\;2^{n+2}\;$ already divides the first factor on the right side, *and the second one is even*, so...

Comment: I think that there might be a slight problem with negative values of $n$ (and I think that the source of the problem is in OP's question, namely, $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ instead of $n\in\mathbb{N}$).

Comment: Ohh I was so close yet so far, thanks so much

Comment: @barakmanos Thanks, yet I think that might be a typo of the OP, since for negative exponents we already get into the realm of rationa numbers, a field, where the notion of "fividing" doesn't mean much...

Comment: Hence my notion of this being s problem within the question itself...

Answer (score 0):

We can write, $a^{2^n}-1=(a^{2^{n-1}}+1)(a^{2^{n-2}}+1)...(a+1)(a-1).$

Now observe that there are $2^{n+1}$ factors above. As $a$ is odd, any one of $a+1$ or $a-1$ is divisible by 4 and the rest $2^n$ factors are all even for the same reason. Thus, their product is divisible by $4 \times 2^n.$